# SQL Query counts to get latest records count only

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have table with userID, FY, clientID
I want a SQL statement that gives me the latest interaction count with the client by the user.

Example: In the below table I have User 1 who had interactions with client "10001" in 2024, 23, 22, after that in 2021 he had interaction with other client called "10002" and in the past in 2020, he had interaction with old client "10001".

But, I want to see the latest and current interactions User is having with the clients.
So, it should be 3 for the userID 1

| UserID | FY | ClientID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024 | 10001 |
| 1 | 2023 | 10001 |
| 1 | 2022 | 10001 |
| 1 | 2021 | 10002 |
| 2 | 2024 | 10003 |
| 2 | 2023 | 10003 |
| 3 | 2024 | 10001 |
| 1 | 2020 | 10001 |
|  |  |  |
| 2 | 2016 | 10003 |

Results I am looking for are:

| UserID | FY | ClientID | CountOfRecentInteractions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024 | 10001 | 3 |
| 2 | 2024 | 10003 | 2 |
| 3 | 2024 | 10001 | 1 |

Is this possible with SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Finding the latest row is the easy part. You can use `row_number()`

For the Count of Interactions, that is the `gap and islands` problem. For this,  you can use `LAG()` and compare current with previous row ClientID and set a flag (`g`). After that performing a cumulative sum of the flag will gives you the grouping required

```
with cte1 as
(
  select UserID,
         FY, ClientID,
         g = case when ClientID <> lag(ClientID) over (partition by UserID 
                                                           order by FY desc)
                  then 1
                  else 0
                  end
  from   T
),
cte2 as
(
  select *, grp = sum(g) over(partition by UserID order by FY desc)
  from   cte1
),
cte3 as
(
  select *, 
         CountOfRecentInteractions = count(*) over (partition by UserID, grp),
         Rank = row_number() over (partition by UserID 
                                       order by FY desc)
  from   cte2
)
select UserID, FY, ClientID, CountOfRecentInteractions
from   cte3
where  Rank = 1
order by UserID
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
with rec as (
  select top 1 with ties * from YourTable order by ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by UserID order by FY desc)
  union all select t.*  from rec inner join @TABLE1 t on t.UserID = rec.UserID and t.ClientID = rec.ClientID and t.FY=rec.FY-1
  )
select UserID,MAX(FY) FY,ClientID,COUNT(1) from rec group by UserID,ClientID order by UserID
```